# C++ Roaches project... Extermination function is flawed

Tags: c++

I'm almost done with this program, but something's not right in `main`. Here are the project instructions:

> **Assignment:**
>   Write a program which keeps track of the number of roaches in two adjacent houses for a number of weeks. The count of the roaches in the houses will be determined by the following:
>
> 1. The initial count of roaches for each house is a random number between 10 and 100.
> 2. Each week, the number of roaches increases by 30%.
> 3. The two houses share a wall, through which the roaches may migrate from one to the other. In a given week, if one house has more roaches than the other, roaches from the house with the higher population migrate to the house with the lower population. Specifically, 30% of the difference (rounded down) in population migrates.
> 4. Every four weeks, one of the houses is visited by an exterminator, resulting in a 90% reduction (rounded down) in the number of roaches in that house.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int house, increase, roaches, filthyBeasts; // My variables for my four functions
int initialCount(int house);
int weeklyIncrease(int increase);
int roachesMigration(int more, int fewer, int change);
int exterminationTime (int filthyBeasts);
// My four function prototypes 

int main()
{
    int houseA, houseB;

    houseA = initialCount(houseA); //Initializing the inital count of House A.
    houseB = initialCount(houseB); //Initializing the inital count of House B.

    int week = 0;
    for (week = 0; week < 11; week++) // My for loop iterating up to 11 weeks.
    {
        houseA = weeklyIncrease(houseA);
        houseB = weeklyIncrease(houseB);

        cout << "For week " << week << ", the total number of roaches in House A is " << houseA << endl;
        cout << "For week " << week << ", the total number of roaches in House B is " << houseB << endl;

        if((houseA > houseB)) // Migration option 1
        {
            houseB = roachesMigration(houseA, houseB);
        }
        else if((houseB > houseA)) // Migration option 2
        {
            houseA = roachesMigration(houseA, houseB);
        }


        if ((week + 1) % 4 == 0) // It's extermination time!
        {
            if ((rand() % 2) == 0) // Get a random number between 0 and 1.
            {
                houseB = exterminationTime(houseB);
            }
            else
            {
                houseA = exterminationTime(houseA);                   
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int initialCount(int house) // Initializing both houses to random numbers between 10 and 100.
{
    int num;
    num = (rand() % 91) + 10;
    return num;
}

int weeklyIncrease(int increaseHouses) // Increasing the roaches in both houses by 30% weekly.
{
    int increase = 0;
    increase = (increaseHouses * .3) + increaseHouses;
    return increase;
}

int roachesMigration(int more, int fewer, int change)
{
    more -= change;
    fewer += change;   
    return ((more - fewer) * .3);
}


int exterminationTime(int filthyBeasts) // Getting rid of the filthy little beasts!
{
    filthyBeasts = (filthyBeasts * .1);
    return filthyBeasts;
}
```

There are issues with the migration and extermination functions. I'm receiving an error message from the compiler that says, "error: Semantic Issue: No matching function for call to 'roachesMigration'". Also, at weeks 4 and 8, the randomly selected house should get exterminated, and the number of roaches in that house should be 90% less than the previous week. What do you guys think I should do to correct this issues? I really appreciate all help!

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: I printed the value of weeks and the odd week number that was printed once is now printed twice.

Comment: You're incrementing your loop variable in the `for(;;)` statment and within the loop. Does that seem right to you?

Comment: Changed it to an answer so that I could be more verbose.

Comment: @EarlFuller: I did the indenting for you. Code is for humans. Doubly/triply/decathly  so when you are asking us to read it.

Comment: @EarlFuller: You're getting extra numbers because that's what you're telling it to do. Take out the increments inside the for loop and any `cout` statements that aren't the two "total number of roaches" statements and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: I notice that you're printing the value of `week` out at the end of your for loop.  In other words, your output should be something like:

```
For week 0, the total number of roaches in House A is 4
For week 0, the total number of roaches in House B is 5
0
For week 1, the total number of roaches in House A is 6
For week 1, the total number of roaches in House B is 7
1
```

However, I suspect that the weeks being printed are not what they should be.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I actually want the weeks to be printed in the same way but without the week number separate at the bottom. For example, "For week 0, the total number of roaches in House A is 4. For  week 0, the total number of roaches in House B is 5." What do you think I should do? =)

Answer (score 1):

Also, your `roachesMigration` is wrong. It should change the number of roaches in both houses, but not the total number of roaches. It changes the total, but only the number of roaches in one of the houses.

To change both roach counts, you can

1. have the function calculate only the number of roaches that migrate and add/subtract in the main loop
2. have the function change both values, which requires passing them as references or pointers (I'd recommend references here)

For the first option:

```
int roachesMigration(int more, int fewer)
{
    return ((more - fewer) * 3) / 10;
}
```

And for the second:

```
void roachesMigration(int & more, int & fewer)
{
    int migration = ((more - fewer) * 3) / 10;
    more -= migration;
    fewer += migration;
}
```

If references and pointers have not yet been covered in the course, go with the first option.

Comment: What do you think I should change in the function definition? I'm so lost. Thanks!

Comment: @Earl I added possible implementations.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that I posted the second option instead of the first one. Let me fix this! Sorry! =)

Comment: Option 1 returns `int`, so if you took that, you must have mis-copied. Be aware that with that option, you need to have e.g. `houseA += roachesMigration(houseB,houseA); houseB -= roachesMigration(houseB,houseA);` in `main`. For the second option, don't assign, the function doesn't return a value, just call it. function

Comment: Okay, Daniel, things are making more sense now. Here's my output: 


For week 0, the total number of roaches in House A is 94
For week 0, the total number of roaches in House B is 85
For week 1, the total number of roaches in House A is 11
For week 1, the total number of roaches in House B is 2
For week 2, the total number of roaches in House A is 14
For week 2, the total number of roaches in House B is 2

But I don't know why both houses are being exterminated in week 1 and the number of roaches in House B for week 2 stays the same. Extermination should take place during weeks 4 or 8 only.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at what you're doing with the variable "week". Especially, where it is changing value.

Edit: Daniel expanded his answer while I was typing (or I didn't read it completely), so I removed my contribution to the migration.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I notice that there is a problem with my week variable.

Comment: If I'm following your code changes correctly, at this point you probably want to look at your decision (if) for when the extermination happens, and what the "week" value is when you get there. You may need to adjust your decision calculation.

Comment: I want the exterminations to happen at weeks 4 and 8, which can be expressed using the mod operator. What do you think I should change? My professor doesn't want me to use (if (week == 4) || (week == 8)), for some weird reason.

Comment: Mod is a perfectly fine way of doing it. Think about the first iteration of your loop. Week is 0, right? 0 % {anything} is 0. Therefor, you are exterminating in week 1. So, think about either adjusting your iterator variable to be 1 to 12, or adjusting your mod to be (week + 1) % 4. If you're planning on doing much programming, get used to starting loops with 0.

Comment: As for your prof not wanting you to do (week == 4) || (week == 8), what would you do if he/she changed the assignment to be 10 years instead of 11 weeks? What if the number of weeks to simulate was a program input? Doing it as a mod or some other calculation is much more usable if conditions change.

Comment: Agreed! I'm going to check out what you said right now! But I have another problem, Chuck. Please take a look at the code I'm posting right now and see what's wrong with my migration function in the for loop. I'm getting a compiler error that says, "error: Semantic Issue: No matching function for call to 'roachesMigration'". I don't know what that means! I have fixed the mod issue.

Comment: You have a couple things going on with it. First, the reason for the error, you have 3 parameters but are passing 2 so the compiler can't match them up. Second, the "change" is (more - less) * .3 which you're calculating inside so you don't need to pass it in. Third, you won't affect the "more" and "fewer" values outside the function. Try having the function calculate the change and return that, then add / subtract from your houses outside (Daniel has examples in his post of this).